# Siamese Model with LSTM network fails to train using tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

**Dataset Description**

The dataset contains a set of question pairs and a label which tells if the questions are same. e.g.

> "How do I read and find my YouTube comments?" , "How can I see all my
>   Youtube comments?" , "1"

The goal of the model is to identify if the given question pair is same or different.

**Approach**

I have created a [Siamese network](https://www.quora.com/What-are-Siamese-neural-networks-what-applications-are-they-good-for-and-why) to identify if two questions are same. Following is the model:

```
graph = tf.Graph()

with graph.as_default():
    embedding_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=embedding_matrix.shape, name='embedding_placeholder')
    with tf.variable_scope('siamese_network') as scope:
        labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size, None], name='labels')
        keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='question1_keep_prob')

        with tf.name_scope('question1') as question1_scope:
            question1_inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size, seq_len], name='question1_inputs')

            question1_embedding = tf.get_variable(name='embedding', initializer=embedding_placeholder, trainable=False)
            question1_embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(question1_embedding, question1_inputs)

            question1_lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size)
            question1_drop = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(question1_lstm, output_keep_prob=keep_prob)
            question1_multi_lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([question1_drop] * lstm_layers)

            q1_initial_state = question1_multi_lstm.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)

            question1_outputs, question1_final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(question1_multi_lstm, question1_embed, initial_state=q1_initial_state)

        scope.reuse_variables()

        with tf.name_scope('question2') as question2_scope:
            question2_inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size, seq_len], name='question2_inputs')

            question2_embedding = question1_embedding
            question2_embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(question2_embedding, question2_inputs)

            question2_lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size)
            question2_drop = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(question2_lstm, output_keep_prob=keep_prob)
            question2_multi_lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([question2_drop] * lstm_layers)

            q2_initial_state = question2_multi_lstm.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)

            question2_outputs, question2_final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(question2_multi_lstm, question2_embed, initial_state=q2_initial_state)
```

Calculate the cosine distance using the RNN outputs:

```
with graph.as_default():
    diff = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(question1_outputs[:, -1, :], question2_outputs[:, -1, :])), reduction_indices=1))

    margin = tf.constant(1.) 
    labels = tf.to_float(labels)
    match_loss = tf.expand_dims(tf.square(diff, 'match_term'), 0)
    mismatch_loss = tf.expand_dims(tf.maximum(0., tf.subtract(margin, tf.square(diff)), 'mismatch_term'), 0)

    loss = tf.add(tf.matmul(labels, match_loss), tf.matmul((1 - labels), mismatch_loss), 'loss_add')
    distance = tf.reduce_mean(loss)

    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(distance)
```

Following is the code to train the model:

```
with graph.as_default():
    saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer(), feed_dict={embedding_placeholder: embedding_matrix})

    iteration = 1
    for e in range(epochs):
        summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('/Users/mithun/projects/kaggle/quora_question_pairs/logs', sess.graph)
        summary_writer.add_graph(sess.graph)

        for ii, (x1, x2, y) in enumerate(get_batches(question1_train, question2_train, label_train, batch_size), 1):
            feed = {question1_inputs: x1,
                    question2_inputs: x2,
                    labels: y[:, None],
                    keep_prob: 0.9
                   }
            loss1 = sess.run([distance], feed_dict=feed)

            if iteration%5==0:
                print("Epoch: {}/{}".format(e, epochs),
                      "Iteration: {}".format(iteration),
                      "Train loss: {:.3f}".format(loss1))

            if iteration%50==0:
                val_acc = []
                for x1, x2, y in get_batches(question1_val, question2_val, label_val, batch_size):
                    feed = {question1_inputs: x1,
                            question2_inputs: x2,
                            labels: y[:, None],
                            keep_prob: 1
                           }
                    batch_acc = sess.run([accuracy], feed_dict=feed)
                    val_acc.append(batch_acc)
                print("Val acc: {:.3f}".format(np.mean(val_acc)))
            iteration +=1

    saver.save(sess, "checkpoints/quora_pairs.ckpt")
```

I have trained the above model with about 10,000 labeled data. But, the accuracy is stagnant at around 0.630 and strangely the validation accuracy is same across all the iterations.

```
lstm_size = 64
lstm_layers = 1
batch_size = 128
learning_rate = 0.001
```

Is there anything wrong with the way I have created the model?

Comment: A good first pass for debugging: make the network completely linear and fit it to one or two trivial examples. Once it fits that (surprising how often it doesn't), slowly re-introduce non-linearities. Since the learning task is trivial, you can attribute slow or non-existent learning to dead/saturated non-linearities.

Comment: Hard to say what's with the accuracy (iI'm not familiar with the dataset or the architecture), but a couple of things. Not sure why you wouldn't want to learn your embeddings, but then you should say `trainable=False`, not `trainable='false'`, which will have no effect. Also, it shouldn't hurt but I don't think you need `scope.reuse_variables()`, or `tf.sqrt` for `diff` if you're squaring it two different places later.

Comment: I have updated the question with brief dataset description and the goal of the model. 1) I have set `trainable=False` because I am using a pre-trained word embeddings. 2) I am using Siamese network here, at the high level it involves having two identical networks using the same weights, then we find the distance between the outputs from two networks. If the distance is less than the threshold then they are identical else not. Hence I used `scope.reuse_varables`.

Comment: I would recommend training the network repeatedly on a single mini-batch to see whether it is able to perfectly represent that mini-batch. If not, you are most likely failing to train at all. Make sure your data has no invalid entries (NaNs and Infs for numeric data, maybe empty strings for questions?).

Comment: Thank you. May I know please where is `question1_train` and `question2_train`?

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem with imbalanced datasets like the recently released Quora dataset which you are using. Since the Quora dataset is imbalanced (~63% negative and ~37% positive examples) you need proper initialization of weights. Without weight initialization your solution will be stuck in a local minima and it will train to predict only the negative class. Hence the 63% accuracy, because that is the percentage of 'not similar' questions in your validation data. If you check the results obtained on your validation set you will notice that it predicts all zeros. A truncated normal distribution proposed in He et al., http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01852 is a good alternate for initializing the weights.